# How to run a Jupyter Notebook tool in a server

Tags: python-3.x, django, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, streamlit

I have created data analysis tool using Jupyter Notebook. Currently, I installed python+Jupyter Notebook in virtual machine and my teammates login to VM to use the tool. But, it’s limiting the users as only one person can login at a time. So, moving forward , I want to keep tool in a server so n number of users can use it at a time.

Note: I am from non-it background. Except coding and logic building, don’t have any knowledge on server, web application etc. currently, I built and developed code in Jupyter notebook.. once Jupyter Notebook finishes running user saves notebook as html report as notebook has all plots and statistical tables.

I see some options like streamlite, mercury but I didn’t get any clear idea for my problem. I want to run Jupyter Notebook in the backend and save it as html report but users should run from their own laptops without login to virtual machine or installing anaconda distribution on their laptops

Comment: You'll probably get flagged for a post that doesn't fit topics appropriate here. Does what you are doing work in a pyodide kernel? In other words the web assembly-based version of the typical full Python kernel, ipykernel? If so, you could use [Voici](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voici-demo#voici-demo) to make an app. It would only be running inside their machine. It's very beta though. You may have to adjust things to get a link they can click and save the produced report. You can serve voici from anywhere you can serve a static site. Voila is the version that requires ...

Comment: <continued> a full ipykernel and so you need computing resources running on a server, you can check Voila out [here](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila) and there is [a gallery of Voila examples](https://voila-gallery.org/) where notebooks serve as the basis for dashboards. If you try Voila and use temporary sessions via MyBinder to serve it, you may want to see [this advice about the URL in this post at the Jupyter Discourse Discussion Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/question-about-voila-binder/2981).

Comment: You could also just move from using a single Vm that only allows one user at a time to using [The Littlest JupyterHub](https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/) where 1-100 users can use your content at the same time provided you set it up with enough computational power. You could even use that to serve Voila app versions of your notebook. I haven't done that but there was some old guide [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/bringing-non-technical-users-into-jupyterhub-a7f9acf83571). ...

Comment: <continued> And also see the note at the bottom [here](https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/howto/content/share-data.html#option-3-create-a-directory-for-users-to-share-notebooks-and-other-files) about, "The TLJH Plugin at kafonek/tljh-shared-directory installs voila and sets up the directories as specified above. Include --plugin git+https://github.com/kafonek/tljh-shared-directory in your deployment startup script to install it."